# Azure Automation: Runbook: does it know it's TenantID?

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

Good afternoon

I *guess* that this is relation is true:

```
Azure Tenant
» Azure Subscription
  » Azure Automation
    » Runbook
```

Therefore I have this question:

Is there a PowerShell command which can be used to get the TenantID in which the Runbook is running?

Comment: You want to run the command inside of the runbook or outside of the runbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the command inside of the runbook, you could use this:

```
$servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"        
Write-Output $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId
```

[image]

**Note**: there is a prerequisite, when you create the automation account, you need to select `Create Azure Run As account` with `Yes`, otherwise the `AzureRunAsConnection`
 is not existing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can use this bit:

```
(Get-AzContext).Tenant.Id
```

to find out the GUID of the tenant

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's incomplete: I guess that one must call Get-AutomationConnection, Connect-AzAccount and then Get-AzContext.

Comment: not really. you asked how to know tenantid. thats the answer to that question. you didnt ask how to login to azure powershell

Comment: mmmhhh.... I have asked how a Runbook is able to know the TenantID. If I just add your code to the Runbook, then I do not get the TenantID, therefore, your answer is incomplete and does not help other users: they just get another questions.

Comment: there is no way to use azure powershell cmdlets without logging in, thats quite obvious.